# Git is not using the correct SSH key to autheticate

Tags: git, ssh

I have two repositories in two hosts. I recently configured ssh in GitHub github was working but not the "other" one. So I added the keys to ~/.ssh/config as follows.

```
Host other
    HostName other.host
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    User git

Host github
    HostName github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
    User git
```

However now, git actions to "other" works but not GitHub.

#### I tried

I removed the `know_hosts` file and retried. Seems like ssh is using `id_rsa` key for "github.com"

```
$ git pull
The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.121.4)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
s1n7ax@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I tried restarting sshd

```
sudo systemctl restart sshd.service
```

Comment: `Host github` does not match `github.com`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that when you declare config Host entries, those entries are now part of your URL.

In your case:

```
cd /path/to/local/repo
git remote set-url origin github:<me>/<myrepo>
                          ^^^^^^
```

You need to use the exact `Host` string you set in `~/.ssh/config`: it is a shortcut for `ssh -i  ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 git@github.com`.